# Suppose $|X_n|\leqslant Y$ a.s. for all $n\in\Bbb N$. Show that $\sup|X_n|\leqslant Y$ a.s. too

Tags: measure-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Since $|X_n| \leq Y$ a.s. for all $n$, we have that $\mathcal{P}\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\{|X_n|\leqslant Y\}\right) =1$

So now the solution asses that:
$$\textstyle\mathcal{P}\left(\bigcap^\infty_{n=1}\{|X_n|\leqslant Y\}\right)=1=\mathcal{P}\big(\sup\{|X_n|\leqslant Y\}\big)$$

and clearly, the $\,\sup|X_n|\leqslant Y$ almost surely.

What is not clear to me and so my doubt is: **Why can I rewrite the intersection as the supremum?**

Comment: $Y(\omega)$ is an upper bound for $\{\lvert X_n(\omega)\rvert\}_n$. Now use the definition of supremum

Comment: The sup is the smaller of the upper bounds so will surely be $\leq$ than Y?

Comment: Even If correct, I cannot understand why the intersection in the second row can be written as the sup in the RHS with the equal sign, honestly

Comment: No one is claiming that the intersection can be written as such, maybe it can maybe it can't. It doesn't matter. It only matters that the intersection is contained in $\{\sup_n \lvert X_n\rvert \leq Y\}$.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I can't see what the issue is. If $\lvert X_n(\omega)\rvert \leq Y(\omega)$ for every $n$, then $\sup_n \lvert X_n(\omega)\rvert \leq Y(\omega)$. Conversely, if $\sup_n \lvert X_n(\omega)\rvert \leq Y(\omega)$, then $\lvert X_n (\omega)\rvert \leq \sup_n \lvert X_n(\omega)\rvert \leq Y$, for every $n$ as desired.

Comment: There may be a relevant typo: supremum of sets or supremum of random variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wrong with the notation.

The following statements are equivalent:

- $\omega\in\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\{|X_n|\leq Y\}$
- $\forall n\in\mathbb N_+[X_n(\omega)\leq Y(\omega)]$
- $\sup_n|X_n(\omega)|\leq Y(\omega)$
- $\omega\in\{\sup_n|X_n|\leq Y\}$

This makes us conclude that:$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\{|X_n|\leq Y\}=\{\sup_{n\in\mathbb N_+}|X_n|\leq Y\}$$The RHS does not agree with the expression in your question.

I am not quite familiar with expressions like $$\sup_{i\in I}A_i$$where ever $A_i$ is a set.

It can only be meaningful if there is an order on these sets.

Inclusion for instance, but then I would prefer "union" above "sup".

Comment: Everything's clear. About the notation, honestly, this was the solution given to me, so i'm sorry about that. I've just one question, how would prove that the first statement implies the fourth in the equivalences?

Comment: Not your fault (so you do not have to feel sorry:-)). To go from 1 to 4 is quite a jump. That's why I placed 2 an 3 in between. If you understand $i)\leftrightarrow i+1)$ for $i=1,2,3$ then that is enough. Let me know if one of them is unclear for you.

Comment: Clear from 1 to 2. From 2 to 3 I suppose that, since this is happening for every N, clearly this will happen even for the smaller of the majorants, so for the sup. Is it correct?

Comment: Sounds good. In 2) it is stated that $Y(\omega)$ is an upper bound of the set $\{|X_1(\omega)|, |X_2(\omega)|,\dots\}$. This can be reworded as: the smallest upper bound (i.e. supremum) of that set is less than or the same as $Y(\omega)$. This is expressed in 3).